# manifold sharepoint elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, sharepoint, manifoldcf

I'm trying to create a crawler job in ManifoldCF 2.7.1, I create the elastic output everything is fine, create the SharePoint repository and everything is fine. Now when I'm creating a job and I add the elastic output I cannot see the elasticsearch tab, just Name, Connections Scheduling Paths, Security, and Metadata. Then I run the job and the crawler gets and processes some documents, but at the end, there is nothing in Elasticsearch. If you have any ideas, please ...
By the way, I try with elasticsearch `1.2.1,1.7.0,5.2.0 and 5.4.0` and SharePoint 2010 and 2013, and same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest release (Apache ManifoldCF Plugin for SharePoint 2013, version 0.1, 2014 Jul 28). Fix the path to the tools "14" to 15